# Display a post count from a custom metabox selection

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox, post-meta, user-meta

**I was wondering if this is possible.**

I have a custom post type call projects that displays a metabox with drop down menu. In that drop down menu I have a few choices listed, draft, open, pending, and completed. Once you select which field you would like, I would like the ability to display a post count of that choice on the front end from the selected author only when they are login.

Example would be author A selects complete 4 times on 4 different posts. So when author A logs onto the site he will see on the front end a number 4 with the word completed.

This is what I am using to display the drop down menu

```
 array(
            'name'    => __( 'Project Status', 'projects' ),
            'desc'    => __( '', 'projects' ),
            'id'      => $prefix . 'project_select',
            'type'    => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'Select a Status' => __( 'Select a Status', 'projects' ),
                'Draft' => __( 'Draft', 'projects' ),
                'Open'   => __( 'Open', 'projects' ),
                'Pending'     => __( 'Pending', 'projects' ),
                'Closed'     => __( 'Closed', 'projects' ),
                'Completed'     => __( 'Completed', 'projects' ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function postsCount($meta_value) {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'        => 'custom_post_type', // set you custom post type
        'meta_key'         => 'project_select',
        'meta_value'       => $meta_value,
    );

    $my_posts = get_posts( $args ); 
    $postsCount = count($my_posts);
    return $postsCount;
}
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo postsCount('Draft');
    echo postsCount('Completed');
}
```

or if you want to get all counts by less code, try this:

```
function postsCount() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    $meta_value_array = array( 'Draft', 'Open', 'Pending', 'Closed', 'Completed');
    $postsCount = '<ul>';
    foreach ($meta_value_array as $meta_value) {
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'        => 'custom_post_type', // set you custom post type
            'meta_key'         => 'project_select',
            'meta_value'       => $meta_value,
        );

        $my_posts = get_posts( $args ); 
        $postsCount = count($my_posts);
        $postsCount .= '<li>' .$meta_value. ' ' .$postsCount. '</li>';
    }
    $postsCount .= '</ul>';
    return $postsCount;
}

echo postsCount();
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to what your code does and how it works. This is considered code dumping which is not allowed

Comment: I tried both codes and they do not display a count for the selections. Both codes just display a 0 @AdamMo.

Comment: Sorry I figured it out I had to change the meta_key. Thank you @AdamMo.